# How to solve a differential equation including $\ddot{x}\dot{x}$ term?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation

$$ m \ddot{x} \dot{x} + f \dot{x} = p $$

where $m > 0$, $f > 0$, $p > 0$ are constants. How to solve it analytically?

Comment: As a fisrt step put $y=x'$

Answer (score 2):

Let $v(t)\frac{dx(t)}{dt}$. Then, note that $\frac12\frac{dv^2(t)}{dt}=x'(t)x''(t)$, where $x''(t)=\frac{dv(t)}{dt}$.

Hence, we have

$$\begin{align}
mx'(t)x''(t)&=\frac12m\frac{dv^2(t)}{dt}\\\\
&=-f\frac{dx(t)}{dt}+p\tag 1
\end{align}$$

Integrating both sides of $(1)$ from $0$ to $t$ yields

$$\begin{align}
\frac12m(v^2(t)-v(0)^2)&=-f\int_0^t \,\frac{dx(t)}{dt'}\,dt'+pt\\\\
&=-f(x(t)-x(0))+pt
\end{align}$$

Comment: I don't think you are right. Where is $p$? And the $f$ is a constant.

Comment: @Feynman This is a standard result in classical mechanics; the change is kinetic energy is equal to the work done.  If $f$ is constant, then the integral on the right-hand side is $f(x(t)-x(0))$. And $p=fx'(t)$.  So, the integral over $t$ of $p$ is also $f(x(t)-x(0))$.

Comment: $p$ is also a constant. It is just a different equation.

Comment: If $f$ is a constant, and $p=fx'$, then $p$ cannot be constant.

Comment: $p$ just is a constant and not a momentum.

Comment: You wrote $fx'=p$. So, if $f$ is constant, then $p$ depends on time through $x'(t)$.

Comment: I wrote $m\ddot{x}\dot{x}+f\dot{x}=p,\quad m>0,f>0,p>0$.

Comment: Yes, I know.  If $f$ is constant, then $p$ cannot be. Do you understand?

Comment: Oh, you edited your question after I posted a solution.

Comment: Would the down voter care to comment?

Answer (score 2):

$$m\ddot{x}\dot{x}+f\dot{x}=p$$
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=y(t)\quad\to\quad m\frac{dy}{dt}y+f\:y=p$$
This is a separable ODE :
$$dt=m\frac{y}{p-f\:y}dy$$
Integration $\quad\to\quad t-t_0=-\frac{m}{f^2}\left(f\:y+p\ln|p-f\:y| \right)$

Solving this equation for $y$ requires a special function, the Lambert W(X) function.
$$y=\frac{p}{f}+\frac{p}{f} W\left(X \right) \quad\text{where}\quad X=-\frac{1}{p}e^{-1-\frac{f^2}{mp}(t-t_0)}$$
$$x(t)=\int ydt=\int\left(\frac{p}{f}+\frac{p}{f} W\left(-\frac{1}{p}e^{-1-\frac{f^2}{mp}(t-t_0)} \right) \right)dt$$

Using the known integral $$\int W\left(e^\chi \right)d\chi=\frac{1}{2}\left(W\left(e^\chi \right)+1 \right)^2+\text{constant}$$ the above integral leads to

$$\begin{cases}
x(t)=\frac{p\:t}{f}-\frac{mp^2}{2f^3}\left(W(X)+1 \right)^2+\text{constant} \\
\text{where }\quad X=-\frac{1}{p}e^{-1-\frac{f^2}{mp}(t-t_0)}
\end{cases}$$